# Bootstrap - 2 navbars active state

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have two horizontal navbars in the same page. One is the main navegation bar and is top fixed. The second one controls a custom accordion and is placed on top of it (not fixed).

Anything works fine but the active states of the buttons of the secondary navbar.

**JS**:

```
<script>
  $("#nav1 a").on("click", function(){
   $("#nav1").find(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).parent().addClass("active");   
  });    
  $("#nav2 a").on("click", function(){
   $("#nav2").find(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  });
</script>
```

As I told you, "nav1" active states are working ok. The problem is "nav2".

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surracom/upgbz833/)

Comment: Put your code up on jsfiddle or at least provide the HTML you're using as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ?

```js
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
  $('.collapse').not(this).removeClass('in');
});

$('[data-toggle=collapse]').click(function (e) {
  $('[data-toggle=collapse]').parent('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.navbar {
 margin-bottom:-1px;
    border-radius:0;
}

#submenu {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.collapsing {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="topmenu">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#one">One</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#two">Two</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#three">Three</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="submenu">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav collapse" id="one">
      <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav collapse" id="two">
      <li><a href="#" id="">Two sub 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="">Two sub 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="">Two sub 3</a></li>
    </ul>
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav collapse" id="three">
      <li><a href="#" id="">Three sub 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="">Three sub 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```